# Gnuplot Boxplot: Outliers should look like an empty circle

Tags: gnuplot, boxplot

I'd like to create boxplot with Gnuplot 4.6, terminal Cairolatex. The outliers should look like on http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boxplot

So I need a circle **without** a dot in the centre. My code is

```
set terminal cairolatex pdf standalone header \
"\\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}"
set output 'example.tex'
set yrange [0:25]
set ylabel "y"
set xlabel "x"
set xrange [0:2]

set datafile separator " "
set style fill empty
set style data boxplot
set style boxplot outliers pointtype 6

plot "example.csv" using (1):1 notitle
```

This gives me this dotted outlier. [Link to example.png](http://wwwpub.zih.tu-dresden.de/~s8842867/example.png). Here it's still okay but if there are outliers overlapping the dots are very annoying.

Is there anybody who has a hint for me? I tried other point types (19, 71) and squares, but the dot  won't hide. Thank you!

Comment: The circles display without the dot in the middle for me with the same gnuplot version.

Comment: Hi, Miguel, thanks for your answer. I used Gnuplot 4.6 patchlevel 0 on Debian Linux and there are these dots. Now I plotted it again under Windows with Gnuplot 4.6 patchlevel 6 and there are no dots. Maybe an old bug? Thanks to you I know how to avoid it :)

Comment: You should be able to install a later version on Debian (anything to avoid Windows!) although my experience with Ubuntu is that some terminals might not be available. epslatex at least seems to work fine so you might be able to get away also with other latex-based terminals.